# NGINX try_files weirdness on location with proxy_pass

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-location

So I'm dealing with an app that states it needs a configuration block like so (removed tuning settings I believe irrelevant to issue):

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name app1.mydomain.com;
}

location / {
        proxy_pass http://10.10.10.102:8096/;
    }

location /socket {
        proxy_pass http://10.10.102:8096/socket;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
```

When using this configuration, the app functions properly, or specifically in the console logs of the app I see no errors and the sockets that need to be created/accessed are apparently done so. However, my overall nginx config is a bit more complex and I try to standardize and modularize things in a certain way. I have a configuration which looks more like this, using proxy_pass and upstream blocks:

```
upstream app1_backend {
        server 10.10.10.102:8096;
}

server {
        listen 443 ssl http2;

        server_name app1.mydomain.com;

        location @proxy {
                proxy_pass http://app1_backend;
        }

        location / {
                try_files $uri @proxy;
        }

        location /api {
                try_files $uri @proxy;
        }

        location /socket {
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
                try_files $uri @proxy;
        }
}
```

The above does not work. Namely the application complains that it can't access /socket. If however I change it to the below block, it works:

```
        location /socket {
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
                try_files $uri @proxy/sockets;
        }
```

I don't understand why this. As I believe the whole $uri, namely "/sockets" should be passed onto the proxy address already. Additionally, I have other apps that use the /api block shown successfully without having to append /api onto the proxy.

I don't understand why I need to append /sockets onto my "@proxy" call.

Comment: You use `try_files` to look for local files and if they do not exist, send the request to the upstream server. Do you have local files with URIs that begin with `/socket`? If not, just replace the `try_files $uri @proxy/sockets;` statement with `proxy_pass http://app1_backend;`.

Comment: @RichardSmith - `try_files` can be used to pass to upstream as per my syntax and as per the nginx documentation.  The `/socket` location should work as the `/api` does, they are no necessarily files per-se, but slots that get open by the running application and as such they will not always resolve unless the application has created them.  I understand that simply putting in the `proxy_pass` statement will work, but so should passing them to `@proxy` which contains the `proxy_pass` location.  It is clear that the /api URI is being passed, but not the /socket for each location.

Comment: I think proxy_pass behaves differently if there is a trailing slash or not. Try adding a slash after `app1_backend` in your second configuration.